# Javascript error when trying to push data into json object with formdata

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, object

I am needing to add more data to a json string from a form.

Currently I store the data so it is in this format, I created a jsfiddle of the issue  https://jsfiddle.net/ua9y185t/

```
var previousObject = {fn:"tom",ln:"miller"};

//new data to add
const data = new FormData(e.target);
//stringify and parse 
let m = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(data)));

let obj = [{name:"John", address:"432 main st"}]; 

m.push(obj)

m.append(obj)
```

> Both say not a function

`m` is set to the form data I try to push data to.

Ok,  here is an image of WHAT the 2 pieces of data look like that I want to append/join/add  (not looking to merge or filter or anything,  it is simply a NEW record

I try and do a push, and it breaks.   Is this an object, an array?  I am not sure how to combine this.  Image of it is below

[image: image of the 2 objects]

Comment: All information needed for the question should be in the question. Supplementary links are fine, but the question should be clear without them, if at all possible. That said, the `m` from your fiddle is definitely an object, as are your `json` and `medicationJSON`. Objects don't have `push`. What result were you expecting to get? ... Also, not JSON.

Comment: Tecnical note: there is no such thing as a "JSON object". There are JS objects, which is what you're working with, and there's JSON, which is a _string presentation_ of (a pared down form of) JS objects.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans: More technical note: There is such a thing as "JSON object", but it is not what OP (or a bunch of other people) think :D . 1) JSON object in JavaScript is `JSON`, with properties `parse` and `stringify`. 2) In JSON definition, JSON object is a substring of form `{ "key": value, ... }`, which maps to JavaScript objects (or Ruby Hash, Python dict, etc etc) when parsed. But I am being nitpicky, and you are absolutely correct that `m` is not a JSON object, but a JavaScript object.

Comment: Your `m` is object type . So push can only use in Array . Also `m` is FormData object thus if you want to add some data you can do like **m.append('KeyName', yourWantedDataToAdd)**

Comment: I try to do an append and it says it is not a function.   I understand that this data is not json as json is just a string -  so i gather it is an object for both ?   how can i combine them?

Comment: For the second time, combine them how? _What is your intended result?_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use push function then it should be an Array.I hope it will helps you.

```
const data = new FormData(e.target);
console.log('data', data)
let m = [];
 m =[JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(data)))];
//let m = Object.fromEntries(data);
    console.log('m', m)

let arr = [{"name":"jack miller", "address":"123 main st"}];

let obj = [{"name":"John", "address":"432 main st"}]; 

arr.push(obj)
console.log('arr', arr)
```

m.push(obj)
console.log('m push', m)

Answer (score 0):

Try to create an array and then push both elements to it:

```
const arr = [];
arr.push(obj)
arr.push(data)

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Actually this is now messing up my data as the original data keeps growing with nested new objects .   This only works after the 2nd time, then its all messed up

Comment: I don't exactly know what you mean, what is your "original" data? What should happen after you pushed those objects together in an array? And what is the problem now?